# How to get better graphics than VESA: Intel®Sandybridge Mobile Graphics

Tags: 12.04, laptop, intel-graphics, sandy-bridge

I am currently using the VESA: Intel®Sandybridge Mobile Graphics and I must say, I do not like the appearance of almost everything. My unity is running only on 2D mode. My screen resolution is also night right. I only have the option of 1024 by 768 (4:3) yet my laptop is a 15.6inch. I am new to ubuntu. I like it so far, I just really want better graphics. Beauty and appeal in a machine mean a whole lot to me.

Comment: Are you using **32** or **64** -bit Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

Open terminal ctrl+alt+t or alternatively from you dash, press enter after each command. enter these commands one by one.

```
sudo su
```

and enter your pass word

```
apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

press enter to add this repository, then

```
apt-get update
```

and

```
apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

and finally

```
reboot
```

You can paste the commands using crtl+shift+v in terminal but i recommend you to type them by hand so that you can memorize them.

Comment: Or print this page first ..

Comment: @Pulkit609 
`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-video-intel : Depends: xorg-video-abi-15
                            Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.14.99.902)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`