# Forcing VGA1 secondary screen to CORRECT resolution causes display issues

Tags: 14.04, resolution, vga

In fact I know that my VGA has 1366x768 resolution as it always was in Windows 8.1. After I switched to Ubuntu I can't go any higher than 1024x768 through Display program.

This is how I try to force it, and what the results are:

```
xrandr --newmode "1366x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1366x768_60.00
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1366x768_60.00
```

Well, the image doesn't actually capture the result. my primary (right screen) overlaps to my secondary (left screen) where I see part of my primary on the secondary screen.

[image]

How to do this correctly?

Comment: What video card do you have?

Comment: boddgi.zazen, Sandy Bridge HD Graphics 3000.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/319152/how-to-get-better-graphics-than-vesa-intel%C2%AEsandybridge-mobile-graphics and http://askubuntu.com/questions/87090/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-an-intel-hd-graphics